# How to cite reference in APA style when author names form part of sentence?

Tags: citations, citation-style

When a citation reference is an integral part of a sentence, such as:

> Gordon and Metric provide a wide review of the key mechanisms...

Where and how is it best to place the citation reference (in APA style)?

A) Place the citation as part of the sentence:

> (Gordon & Metric, 2012) provide a wide review...

B) Place the citation right next to the authors' names (the repetition seems a bit awkward to me):

> Gordon and Metric (Gordon & Metric, 2012) provide a wide review...

C) Place the citation at the end of the sentence:

> Gordon and Metric provide a wide review [...] of the financial crisis (Gordon & Metric, 2012).

Comment: Isn't it "Gordon and Metric (2012) provide a wide review of the key mechanisms..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, as is pointed out by @JeffE, it should be: "Gordon and Metric (2012) provide a wide review of the key mechanisms..."

For a reference, please visit the following page to have a comprehensive collection of APA citation examples.

[APA Citation Examples - University of Maryland University College](http://www.umuc.edu/library/libhow/apa_examples.cfm)